For two surfaces with local param. on the same interval show that : If the first fundamental forms are equal then the Gauss Curvatures are equal
I've been studying for an upcoming exam on Differential Geometry I and I'm a bit stumped on the last question of a previous exam. Would love any insights.
Problem:
Let $M$ and $S$ be regular surfaces with local parameterizations on the same open interval of $R^2$ such that for any point $(u,v), I_M(u,v)=I_S(u,v)$. Show that the Gaussian Curvatures of $M$ and $S$ are the same at each point $(u,v)$. Then, show that if a flat surface is minimal, it is part of a plane.
Would love help with both questions but especially the first one. In my mind Gaussian Curvature($K$) is defined as $(eg-f^2)/EG-F^2$ where e,g,f are the fundamental quantities of the second fundamental form and E,G,F are the fundamental quantities of the first fundamental form.
I also tried toying around with the definition of $K$ as the determinant of the Weingarten matrix, but again that matrix also depends on e,f,g.
Searching around I also came across thie question where the answers provide surfaces with same first fundamental form but different curvature
Any help with any of those two questions is greatly appreciated. Thank you!!

Different second fundamental forms does not mean different curvatures. Go read some more. Learn Gauss’s Theorema Egregium. The second question is plain wrong — pun intended.

@TedShifrin Hi! Thank you for your response. The Theorema Egregium is not part of the syllabus, that's why I did not mention it. It is possible the syllabus has been revised but I doubt it. Will inquire about it tommorow. Second question is not wrong, I just confused level with flat. I managed to solve it once I cleared that confusion. Will edit the question to use correct terminology and then upload my own solution once I am back at my desk.

Ah, now it is correct and immediate.
